# Defining a data type

Tags: haskell

What sort of data type do I need in order for these class declarations to work?

```
class YesNo a where
   yesno :: a -> Bool

instance YesNo Int where
   yesno 0 = False
   yesno _ = True

instance YesNo [a] where
   yesno [] = False
   yesno _ = True

instance YesNo Bool where
   yesno = id

instance YesNo (Maybe a) where
   yesno (Just _) = True
   yesno Nothing = False
```

At the moment `*Main> :t yesno` produces `<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: yesno`, presumably because I need to define an appropriate data type.

It was suggested I add the constraint `(YesNo a) =>` to the type of `yesno` doesn't seem to work (I still get `<interactive>:14:1: error: Variable not in scope` when asking for the type of `yesno`:

```
  *Main> :l experiment
  [1 of 3] Compiling Geometry         ( Geometry.hs, interpreted )
  [2 of 3] Compiling Shapes           ( Shapes.hs, interpreted )
  [3 of 3] Compiling Main             ( experiment.hs, interpreted )
  Ok, three modules loaded.
  *Main> :t yesno

<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: yesno
```

Comment: `yesno` has type `(YesNo a) => a -> Bool`. Have you tried to type all this at the prompt? I'd recommend saving it as a file and loading it from the file. (Although the bodies of those `class` and `instance` declarations need to be indented.)

Comment: @Robin Zigmond: Ah yes, they were indented in the file. Adding the constraint `(YesNo a) =>` doesn't seem to work (I still get `<interactive>:14:1: error:
    Variable not in scope` when asking for the type of `yesno`.

Comment: no, you don't need to put the constraint in your file - I was just saying that's what the reported type should be. Let me try it now, I think you must be doing something wrong but I can't say for sure until I've tried myself.

Comment: well it works fine for me, I copied your code, loaded it into GHCI, put in `:t yesno`, and as expected got the output `yesno :: YesNo a => a -> Bool`. Can you describe *exactly* what you're doing, perhaps with a screenshot?

Comment: @Robin Zigmond: I have exactly the code in my question in a file which I have been loading successfully. I load it, and receive the error I mentioned.

Comment: @user65526 After your edit, your code doesn't compile anymore. So if you were really loading a file with those contents, you'd be getting an error message. If you were loading a file with the code before the edit (i.e. without the `(YesNo a) =>`), you would be getting no errors, but you wouldn't be getting any messages about "Compiling Geometry" or "Compiling Shape" as those modules aren't mentioned anywhere in the code. In other words: you're not loading the file that contains the code from your question - you're loading some other file.

Comment: @sepp2k, in my file I have `import Geometry` and `import Shapes` (corresponding to two separate files I have been using successfully until now) which is why I am getting the messages about "Compiling Geometry", etc, just as I wish to. If I get rid of the suggested class constraint `(YesNot a) =>` I still get the error report.

Comment: @user65526 - `(YesNo a) =>` was not a "suggested class constraint". I was merely trying to point out what the inferred type of the `yesno` function would be (and indeed is). That should NOT go in your file anywhere, and to avoid all possible doubt, I wasn't trying to tell you to add it :)

Comment: by the way, now that we know you're importing other files, I think we need to see more. You've clearly got `import`s in your file, perhaps you have `export`s too and aren't exporting `yesno`?

Comment: Please show us the actual contents of the file you're loading or, even better, try to load a file that actually contains exactly the code in your question (without the `(YesNo a) =>`) and nothing else. Then when you realize that it works perfectly fine with that file, try to figure out what's different about your `experiment` file.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Exports don't matter when loading a file with `:l`. That is, even if a definition isn't exported, you can still access in GHCi when loading the file with `:l`. So the issue must be something else. I'm still not convinced that OP isn't just loading the wrong file (especially since there apparently was no compilation error when OP tried the version with the added constraint in it).

Comment: @sepp2k: The code works when I load it at the prompt. So I suppose it must be something in the file `experiment.hs`

Comment: @sepp2k: there was a compilation error when I loaded with the additional constraint. The same error I get when loading without the constraint.

Comment: @sepp2k - thanks for the explanation, I wasn't sure

Comment: If it says "Ok, three modules loaded", that means there was no compilation error when loading the file. If there was a different message, you need to tell us that. But according to the GHCi output you posted in the question, the file compiled without errors.

Comment: @sepp2k: Yes, it loads. But then `:t yesno` produces `<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: yesno`

Comment: I know that. I'm saying that it still loaded when you put an actual error in the file. If there's an error in the file, it shouldn't load. I therefore concluded that you're loading a different file than the one you're editing.

Comment: @user65526 did you get this sorted? I must admit I'm kind of intrigued as to what you were doing wrong. If you didn't figure it out yet, edit the question with the complete contents of your `experiment.hs` so we can see exactly what you're working with.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond: It works now. I think I was loading a different file. However, I find it mystifying since the files seem to have the same content.